# EF Core get records where two properties match a pair of properties from a list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a List of Foo, where Foo is:

```
public class Foo
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and a database entity Bar:

```
public partial class Bar
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Count { get; set; }
  etc...
}
```

I want to get Bars where the Id and Name match a Foo in the List. Something like:

```
var records = databaseContext.Bar
  .Where(r => FooList.Contains(*a Foo with Id and Name matching r.Id and r.Name*))
  .ToArray()
```

How can I get these records in an efficient and clean way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netcore-3.1) method:

```
var records = databaseContext.Bar
  .Where(r => FooList.Any(item => item.Id == r.Id && item.Name == r.Name))
  .ToArray();
```

**Update**

Including the comment I had left, when we spotted some issues:

One fast solution, not optimal it would be to load all Bar and then perform the `Any` call,

```
databaseContext.Bar.ToList()
                   .Where(r => FooList.Any(item => item.Id == r.Id && item.Name == r.Name))
                   .ToArray();
```

Comment: Yes, Any is what I needed here, thanks!

Comment: @aforest-ccc You are very welcome ! I am glad that I helped.

Comment: Negative. This would have been an answer for LINQ to Objects. For EF Core this would lead to either client evaluation (EFC 1.x, EFC2.x if enabled) or runtime exception (EFC3.x +).

Comment: @IvanStoev fair...provided that aforest-ccc verify that this **didn't** work. If he verifies that is working, I could definitely improve the quality of the answer by adding that you wrote, but in that case the negative vote doesn't make any sense for me IMHO.

Comment: @aforest-ccc could you please verify that this solution worked ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately everything that Gert Arnold wrote in the linked EF post still applies to EF Core (as of now, also in the latest EFC 5.0 RC2, so I guess it won't be fixed soon).

Comment: @Christos I'm afraid I can verify that it doesn't work, which is a shame. The posted link is informative but disappointing.

Comment: @aforest-ccc So, when you wrote.."is what I needed", you didn't verify that works. Correct ? One fast solution,  _not optimal_ it would be to load all Bar and then perform the Any call, `databaseContext.Bar.ToList().Where(r => FooList.Any(item => item.Id == r.Id && item.Name == r.Name)).ToArray();`.

Comment: Yeah this won't work without enumerating with a ToList() call beforehand.